# Does almost sure convergence imply almost sure convergence of conditional expectations?

Tags: probability-theory

So I'm looking for a counter example to show : $X_n\xrightarrow{a.s.}  X \not\Rightarrow E(X_n|\mathcal{D})\xrightarrow{a.s.} E(X|\mathcal{D}).$

I thought maybe it would be helpful if $X_n \downarrow X $ a.s., to avoid Lebesgue's theorem. Do you think my above claim holds true and if so have any suggestion for an example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convergence a.s. does not imply convergence in mean.

---

E.g. take $X_n=n\mathsf1_{[0,\frac1n]}$ and $X=0$ on probability space $([0,1],\mathcal B((0,1)),\lambda)$.

Then $X_n\stackrel{a.s.}{\to}X$ but if for $\mathcal D$ we take $\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$ then: $$\mathbb E[X_n\mid\mathcal D]=\mathbb EX_n=1\neq0=\mathbb EX=\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal D]$$ for every $n$.

So this provides a counterexample.